# custom map with custom routes

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, maps

I'm beginning for develop a app with a custom map and it have to allowed custom routes (because no streets inbetween).
I found much about custom maps (route-me, cloudmade, mapbox), but I've found nothing about, how to add some custom routes at a custom map.

e.g.: At a very big shopping center, the customer will go from his current location to another shop in the shopping center.

So google_maps do not have a detailed structure of this shopping centre (any shopping center), that's why I have to create a custom one. It's the same for the custom routes from current location to locationX. It have to show it at a custom map.

Any ideas?

Comment: I folks,
one opinion is awiloc. It's a way of routing on closed rooms without gps.

Comment: http://trimaps.com maybe does that.

Comment: @kurtanamo Did you find anything useful ? Because I have same kind of project ahead.

Comment: @RoNiT I'm sorry not really...only way to do this (as soon as I know) is to create it on yourself, with custom map (image) and a xy coordinates over that.

Comment: @kurtanamo Well, Thanx for replying. I am studying http://www.trimaps.com & http://www.cartotype.com, lets see if they helps. :)